# How to export virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm new to virtualenv but I'm writting django app and finally I will have to deploy it somehow.

So lets assume I have my app working on my local virtualenv where I installed all the required libraries. What I want to do now, is to run some kind of script, that will take my virtualenv, check what's installed inside and produce a script that will install all these libraries on fresh virtualenv on other machine. How this can be done? Please help.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You don't copy paste your virtualenv. You export the list of all the packages installed like -

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then push the `requirements.txt` file to anywhere you want to deploy the code, and then just do what you did on dev machine -

```
$ virtualenv <env_name>
$ source <env_name>/bin/activate
(<env_name>)$ pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt
```

And there you have all your packages installed with the exact version.

You can also look into [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) to automate this task, with a function like this -

```
def pip_install():
    with cd(env.path):
        with prefix('source venv/bin/activate'):
            run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
```

Comment: Fair enough, but that's a shame there is no dedicated commandand and fabric integration ;)

Comment: I just added fabric to the answer. You can easily write a fabric function to do the same. Hardly few lines of code.

Comment: Added a sample function to get you started.

Comment: This is totally insufficient if you've used the virtual environment for anything more complicated than tracking package versions. E.g., if you have different python paths for virtual virtual environments, or are configuring other aspects of the environment. Even something as simple as the python version is use is overlooked by this approach!

Comment: However, as I've looked in to this more, it seems that virtualenv is really not equipped for supporting containment of this kind of more complex environment management , even though they support such customization... so maybe I am just using the tool wrong.

Comment: What if the destination computer does not have internet connectivity? That's the case with a lot of production deployments. Is there any solution for that case?

Comment: What does this have to do with `export`?

Answer (score 4):

You can install virtualenvwrapper and try [cpvirtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#cpvirtualenv), but the developers advise caution here:

> Warning
>
> Copying virtual environments is not well supported. Each virtualenv
>   has path information hard-coded into it, and there may be cases where
>   the copy code does not know it needs to update a particular file. Use
>   with caution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package that can do this for you automatically called [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/).  Here's a simple implementation:

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs /path/to/project
```

This will automatically create a `requirements.txt` in the directory in which you point the package.

`pipreqs` only exports packages that are used within your specific project, not an exhaustive list of packages in the environment. Here's their github documentation: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Answer (score -2):

If it is going to be on the same path you can tar it and extract it on another machine. If all the same dependencies, libraries etc are available on the target machine it will work.

Comment: This is ambiguous. How does one ensure that all of the "dependencies, libraries etc are available on the target machine?"